# Jquery keypress keydown error

Tags: jquery, keypress, keydown

Sir,I'm new to jquery.I have a chat app.there's two pages.ine for select conversations.if click one conversation.it send the conversation id to 2nd page.in 2nd page.load messages according to conversation.

```
<li id="1"> conversation 1 </li>
<li id="2"> conversation 2 </li>



$('li').click(function() {
    var groupid = this.id;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'getmessages.php',
        data: 'groupid=' + groupid,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(r) {
            $('#output').html(r);
        }
    });
});
```

In 2n page(getmessages.php) fetch messages using php.and send new message using

```
$('#sendbutton').click(function(){ 
// send message
});
```

Also I have code for send message when click 'enter' key.

```
$(document).keypress(function(e){
alert('test') ; //this alert is for test
If(e.which ==13){    // send message
}
});
```

Sendbutton click function working. But in keypress function, if we click conversation twice(on 1st page), It send message twice when click enter.(show 'test' alert twice) . If click 3 times it send same message 3 times and so on.
How do I fix this.thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Because hitting "Enter" when focus is on a button triggers the "click" event natively. You also get a "keypress" event, and from that you trigger the "click" event again.

Comment: Thanks.do you know how to disable li on click. $(this).off(); working. But for 1st li only.if click 2nd li,2nd should be disable and 1st should be enable. And so on.I need prevent click li twice same time

Comment: How about replace `keypress` with `keydown`?